# How to add a column to the existing DataFrame and using window function to add specific rows in the new column using Scala/Spark 2.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Eg: I would like to add the quantity sold by the date.

```
Date       Quantity
11/4/2017    20 
11/4/2017    23 
11/4/2017    12 
11/5/2017    18
11/5/2017    12
```

Output with the new Column:

```
Date        Quantity, New_Column
11/4/2017      20        55
11/4/2017      23        55
11/4/2017      12        55
11/5/2017      18        30
11/5/2017      12        30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `sum` as a window function by specifying a *WindowSpec*:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df.withColumn("New_Column", sum("Quantity").over(Window.partitionBy("Date"))).show
+---------+--------+----------+
|     Date|Quantity|New_Column|
+---------+--------+----------+
|11/5/2017|      18|        30|
|11/5/2017|      12|        30|
|11/4/2017|      20|        55|
|11/4/2017|      23|        55|
|11/4/2017|      12|        55|
+---------+--------+----------+
```